# How to retrieve request or locale within an entity instance?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, autowired

For some translation purpose, I need to retrieve the request or the locale in my entities.

I tried to do what is [written here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html) but it's not working with entities.

```
/**
 * AccessoryType constructor.
 *
 * @param RequestStack $requestStack
 */
public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
    $this->request=$requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
}
```

I get the following error message (which is to be excepted I guess...)

> Too few arguments to function App\Entity\Map::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/sphere/src/Controller/MapController.php on line 34 and exactly 1 expected

My end goal is to have the right getter called based on the locale, mostly for forms, which use `__toString()` to generate fields name.

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString() {
    if($this->request->getLocale() != 'en') {
        $call='getName'.ucfirst($this->request->getLocale());

        return strlen($this->$call()) > 0 ? $this->$call() : $this->getName();
    } else {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to retrieve the request or locale within an entity?

Comment: Do not inject services into your entity. Instead translate in your controller or in twig or if it gives you more comfort create your own service

Comment: @FrankB it's to have an automatic translation ton `__toString()`. I require the current locale. All I really need is the current locale. Don't need to be a service.

Comment: so in twig or your controller. No services are available to your entity.

Comment: Well, I can't change the value of `__toString()` in twig or controller... :/

Comment: why not? can you give a code example? i mean the twig part

Comment: and the controller or Twig part? which Symfony version?

Comment: @FrankB Symfony 5 (tagged), and controller is just basic for now, didn't add a single line in it yet. Nothing in twig as well, app is brand new

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#basic-translation

Comment: @FrankB this translate static text. Not text from database. There are Gedmo and Knp bundle for translation, but too heavy for just 2 locale...

Comment: replace the static text for an instance of your entity ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean @FrankB

Comment: '$translated = $translator->trans($myEntity->__toString());'

Answer (score 1):

By default, entities are not autowired, so services are not injected in entities.

You can find this in this `services.yaml` declaration (yours could be different if you changed it, but in all likelihood this is what you have):

```
# services.yaml
# ...
# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
  # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
  App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

The `exclude` is making all classes within `src/Entity` to be excluded from autowiring.

You *could* change this. E.g. you could remove `Entity` from that list, but you would be also configuring all your entities into services, which clearly doesn't make sense.

In general, the idea of having to inject services into your entity classes does not seem particularly good. Injecting the request stack looks to particularly out of place, since that's a front-end concern that's completely irrelevant for a model entity.

Leave the translation to remain a front-end concern, and services out of your entities.

Comment: I have no issues with front end translation. My problem is mostly forms, using `toString()` method to, for example, generate `<select>` choices texts. I can't translate such things manually (unless I dump the database text into a translation file I guess). Anyway, I understand the fact that turning entities into services isn't recommanded. Guess I will look for a work-around. Thanks